# How to specify a complex absolute reference in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page containing some radiobuttons and some related `fieldset`s, each one with its own id.
I want to hide/view the `div` depending on a specific radiobutton.

The attached [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjdv3xuL/) do the job.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="FS1">External fieldset with radiobuttons

  <div class="row">
    <input checked="checked" id="R1" name="Group1" type="radio" value="1"/>
    <label for="R1">Element 1</label>
    <input id="R2" name="Group1" type="radio" value="2"/>
    <label for="R2">Element 2</label>
    <input id="R3" name="Group1" type="radio" value="3"/>
    <label for="R3">Element 3</label>
    <fieldset class="fs" id="FS1-1">
      <legend>Header element 1</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputText1" type="text"/>
        <label for="exampleInputText1">Input field in the first element</label></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fs" id="FS1-2">
      <legend>Header element 2</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputText2" type="text"/>
        <label for="exampleInputText2">This is the input field for the second</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fs" id="FS1-3">
      <legend>Header element 3</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputText3" type="text"/>
        <label for="exampleInputText3">And this is the last input field</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS

```
#FS1 div input:not(:checked) ~ #FS1-1, #FS1-2, #FS1-3 { display: none; } /* to hide all the detail elements */
#FS1 div input[value="1"]:checked ~ #FS1-1 { display: block; } /* to show only the 1th elem */
#FS1 div input[value="2"]:checked ~ #FS1-2 { display: block; } /* to show only the 2nd */
#FS1 div input[value="3"]:checked ~ #FS1-3 { display: block; } /* to show only the 3rd */
```

Now, what I want to achieve, is to relocate the `fieldset` outside the `div`, at the end of the fragment, but this brokes the css references and the fragment doesn't run anymore.

The following is the desired fragment, not running. 
I need suggestions on how to redefine the CSS

```
<div id="FS1">External fieldset with radiobuttons

  <div class="row">
    <input checked="checked" id="R1" name="Group1" type="radio" value="1"/>
    <label for="R1">Element 1</label>
    <input id="R2" name="Group1" type="radio" value="2"/>
    <label for="R2">Element 2</label>
    <input id="R3" name="Group1" type="radio" value="3"/>
    <label for="R3">Element 3</label>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="fs" id="FS1-1">
    <legend>Header element 1</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputText1" type="text"/>
      <label for="exampleInputText1">Input field in the first element</label></div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="fs" id="FS1-2">
    <legend>Header element 2</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputText2" type="text"/>
      <label for="exampleInputText2">This is the input field for the second</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="fs" id="FS1-3">
    <legend>Header element 3</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputText3" type="text"/>
      <label for="exampleInputText3">And this is the last input field</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you're asking cannot be achieved with plain `CSS`, but a solution could be achieved with `Javascript`.

Here is why it is not possible with your current HTML structure, as your current HTML structure looks like this:

[image]

With corresponding (simplified) code:

```css
#FS1 div input:not(:checked) ~ #FS1-1, #FS1-2, #FS1-3 { display: none; } /* to hide all the detail elements */
#FS1 div input[value="1"]:checked ~ #FS1-1 { display: block; } /* to show only the 1th elem */
#FS1 div input[value="2"]:checked ~ #FS1-2 { display: block; } /* to show only the 2nd */
#FS1 div input[value="3"]:checked ~ #FS1-3 { display: block; } /* to show only the 3rd */
```

```html
<div id="FS1">
  <div class="row">
    <input checked="checked" id="R1" name="Group1" type="radio" value="1"/>    
    <fieldset class="fs" id="FS1-1"></fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fs" id="FS1-2"></fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fs" id="FS1-3"></fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a simple example, I will explain *why* this line of code works:

```
#FS1 div input[value="1"]:checked ~ #FS1-1 { display: block; }
```

1. Accesses id `FS1`
2. Accesses HTML entity `div` which is a *child* of `FS1`
3. Accesses the HTML entity `input` for state `:checked` and internal `value="1"`
4. Accesses the `sibling` element (`~`) of id `FS1-1`
5. Sets the property of `display: block` for `FS1-1`

The key thing to note is that the `sibling` element is selected.

With your proposed changesets to the HTML (see below), you would be required to access the `parent` element of the HTML entity `input` for state `:checked` and internal `value="1"` and then from there access the `sibling`, as `FS1-1` no longer resides in the `div class="row"`, rather outside it.

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Limitations):

> **Some noted limitations of the current capabilities of CSS include:** 
>   Selectors are unable to ascend. CSS currently offers no way to select a parent or ancestor of an element that satisfies certain criteria.

This has also been touched on here: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/11700321)

> There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS. In the meantime, you'll have to resort to JavaScript if you need to select a parent element.

Honestly, it's probably not worth the fight, leave the `fieldset` inside the `div class="row"` if possible.

Here are the relevant resources if you wish to go ahead and convert this to a `Javascript` solution:

- [Javascript Parent Element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp)
- [Set Style Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp)
- [Get Attribute Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)
- [Next Sibling Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp)

Comment: Thank you EGC for your explanation. I was looking for a different solution, using absolute references: I'd like to describe a rule similar to this (sintax is invented): ```#FS1-1 [#FS1 div input[value="1"]:checked] {display: block;}```